# Getting Insufficient Access on task record while trying to edit it

Tags: sharing, tasks, userrecordaccess

I have a Job Record and Two Users like User A and User B.

User A creates a task on Job Record 123 and tasked it to User B. Now User A is created by of this newly created record and user B is owner of this newly created Task.

User A has edit permission on Job record 123 but when he try to changes status of this newly created task he gets "Insufficient Access".

Can anyone please explain -
1) Why User A getting "Insufficient Access" error while trying to edit status of created task even if User A has edit permission on associated job record?

2) How can i make User A able to edit this task record?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: whats OWD of your activity object in your org?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava OWD is Controlled by Parent. Thanks

Comment: There is system permission "Edit Task" on profile, worth to check and try!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the help information on Access to Activities and Calendars https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_access.htm, you need to give people Modify All permission on the Job records or just Modify All Data.

It is not very intuitive that having Edit permission on the Job record is not enough, but that's how I read the help article.

Comment: User A already has Modify All permission on Job Object but still he is getting this exception.

Comment: Hmm... and you have checked all the other conditions listed in that help article?

Comment: Yes... User A has Modify all on Job object then i don't think i need to check some other conditions... what do you say?